# Admin Inline when model has 2 Foreign Keys to same model?

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-keys

I've created a referral system on my website. Admittedly, it's late and this might not be the right sort of relationship.

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    referred=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="referred")
    referrer=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="referrer")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

What would others recommend to represent this relationship? If this is about right, is there a way for me to turn this into a pseudo inline for the User Admin?  It's not allowed as currently constructed because there are two foreign keys to teh same table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a ManyToMany relationship between User and itself - the Referral class itself does not add anything to the relationship.

Normally, you can just add the ManyToManyField to the model and it will be displayed in the admin - but I'm guessing that the User class you reference is the built-in django.contrib.auth User, which you can't directly modify. So one way would be to define a UserProfile class which has a ForeignKey to User, and add the ManyToMany relationship there.

**Edit in response to comment** No, that's not quite what I meant. I'm saying you should drop the Referral class completely. A model which is just two FKs and nothing else - whether they're both to the same model or not - is the through table of a M2M relationship. That relationship, in your case, is between User and itself - but as I say, since you don't want to change User, it is between a new UserProfile model and itself.

Comment: Right about using the built in User model, which I don't want to alter.  The Referral class is essentially a UserProfile class here, right...except it doesn't have the additional queryset functionality that's derived from naming it UserProfile(I should probably make the change)

Comment: Also, I'm a bit confused by your describing it as a M2M field.  A referred user can only have 1 referrer.  I would think that it's a Many To One Relationship, hence the Foreign Key.  What am I missing?

Comment: What about intermediate models for symmetrical ManyToManyFields that define extra fields?